# Store into variable a string that changes dynamically

Tags: shell, awk, sed

I'm quite new unix in shell scripting so I assume I need help regarding the following issue:

I want to store into a variable a string of a log text that changes dynamically. E.x one time you run the program that creates this log, this string may be ***server1*** and the next time ***server238***. I have found ways to find the first occurrence of this string through sed or grep and cut. However since the log file that this software creates may differ from version to version I can't count on a specific line that contains this string. E.x one version may log "The server you are using is server98" and the next one to "Used server is server98". Is there a way through sed or awk that this string may be retrieved regardless of the log layout.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Oh, you seem to be fond of [Camus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albert_Camus)!  Good.

Comment: That is cruel, mr @devnull :-)

Comment: @MarkSetchell What's cruel about that?  [The Myth of Sisyphus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Myth_of_Sisyphus) is an excellent read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd go with:

```
server=$(grep -Eo 'server[0-9]+' file | head -n 1)
```

to find any occurrence of the word `server` followed by some digits, e.g. server3, server98

`-E` means to use Extended regular expressions (i.e. \d+ for multiple digits)

`-o` means only output the matching part of the string - not the whole line that contains it.

Here it is in action on OSX:

```
cat file
server9 
fred server98 fred
3

/usr/bin/grep -Eo 'server[0-9]+' file
server9
server98
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I tried but the variable was empty.Could you explain what the argument -Eo stands for because I haven't found it in any reference. I tried also with grep -E but the variable was also empty.

Comment: I have explained the switches I used. They are the ones on a Mac under OSX but you should be able to find the equivalent on any Unix/Linux if you do `man grep` and then `/xtended`. Actually, I think Linux uses GNU grep which does Extended Regexes anyway, so you can probably omit it on Linux.

Comment: Hi again I tried it both in Ubuntu and OSx but I had the same result.
I also tried with only grep -o but the same. I may have misconceived something.

Comment: This worked but it stored all the occurrences of server91. How can this be minimized to just one?

Comment: I have modified my answer to just grab the first occurrence, by using `head -n 1`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
MY_VAR="$(sed -n 's/^.*\(server[0-9][0-9]*\).*$/\1/p' my_file.log | sort -u)"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The echo of the variable showed that it stored all the occurrences but only with numbers. So it stored the following
91 91 91 91 91 91 91 91 91 91 91
I may be misunderstood but I would like only one occurrence with the whole alphanumeric "server91" to be stored in the variable.